# How to join/align axes for a perfect corner in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the following matplotlib rc parameter file, but I find that the axes are not fully closed or joined to form a perfect corner as shown in the figure:

[image]

The matplotlibrc parameter file is given below:

```
lines.linewidth : 1.0               # Line width (in points).
lines.linestyle : -                 # Line style.
lines.color : blue                  # Line color.


font.family : serif
font.serif : Palatino, Bitstream Vera Serif, New Century Schoolbook, Century Schoolbook L, Utopia, ITC Bookman, Bookman, Nimbus Roman No9 L, Times New Roman, Times, Charter, serif

text.color : black
text.usetex : true


axes.facecolor : FFFFFF         # axes background color
axes.edgecolor : 000000         # axes edge color
axes.linewidth : 1.0            # edge linewidth
axes.grid : true                # display grid or not
axes.titlesize : large          # fontsize of the axes title
axes.labelsize : 9              # fontsize of the x any y labels
axes.labelweight : normal       # weight of the x and y labels
axes.labelcolor : 000000
axes.axisbelow : true
axes.formatter.limits : -7, 7
axes.color_cycle : E41A1C, 377EB8, 4DAF4A, 984EA3, FF7F00, FFFF33, A65628, F781BF, 999999       # color cycle for plot lines
polaraxes.grid : true           # display grid on polar axes
axes3d.grid : true              # display grid on 3d axes


xtick.major.size : 4            # Major tick size (in points).
xtick.minor.size : 2            # Minor tick size (in points).
xtick.major.width : 1           # Major tick width (in points).
xtick.minor.width : 1           # Minor tick width (in points).
xtick.major.pad : 6             # Distance to major tick label (in points).
xtick.minor.pad : 6             # Distance to the minor tick label (in points).
xtick.color : 000000            # Tick label colors.
xtick.labelsize : 8             # Tick label font size (in points).
xtick.direction : in            # Tick direction

ytick.major.size : 4            # Major tick size (in points).
ytick.minor.size : 2            # Minor tick size (in points).
ytick.major.width : 1           # Major tick width (in points).
ytick.minor.width : 1           # Minor tick width (in points).
ytick.major.pad : 6             # Distance to major tick label (in points).
ytick.minor.pad : 6             # Distance to the minor tick label (in points).
ytick.color : 000000            # Tick label colors.
ytick.labelsize : 8             # Tick label font size (in points).
ytick.direction : in            # Tick direction


grid.color : 999999             # Grid color.
grid.linestyle : :              # Grid line style.
grid.linewidth : 0.5            # Grid line width (in points).
grid.alpha : 1.0                # Grid line transparency.


legend.fancybox : true      # if true, use a rounded box for the
legend.isaxes : true
legend.numpoints : 1            # the number of points in the legend line
legend.fontsize : 9
legend.borderpad : 0.5          # border whitespace in fontsize units
legend.markerscale : 1.0        # the relative size of legend markers vs. original
legend.labelspacing : 0.5       # the vertical space between the legend entries in fraction of fontsize
legend.handlelength : 2.        # the length of the legend lines in fraction of fontsize
legend.handleheight : 0.7       # the height of the legend handle in fraction of fontsize
legend.handletextpad : 0.8      # the space between the legend line and legend text in fraction of fontsize
legend.borderaxespad : 0.5      # the border between the axes and legend edge in fraction of fontsize
legend.columnspacing : 2.       # the border between the axes and legend edge in fraction of fontsize
legend.shadow : false
legend.frameon : true           # whether or not to draw a frame around legend
legend.scatterpoints : 1        # number of scatter points
```

Have I set something wrong in the settings or is there another way of properly aligning the axes?

**Update**

It seems that the default settings have the same problem as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I've checked a couple of my plots and they don't do this. When you use a different (default) rc file do you see this? If so, comment out half your rc file at a time to zoom in on the relevant change. Also, are you using a default plot, or spines, or what?

Comment: Did you try increasing the axes line width?

Comment: ... do you mean that *you've* identified increasing the axes line width as the problem in *your* plot?

Comment: No, it exists for all line widths, but the effect becomes more pronounced at larger line widths.

Comment: Then you've probably diagnosed the problem and you could either ask for a fix in the matplotlib code or plot an unclipped line-width square centered at (0,0) to fix it yourself. (I don't have the problem at all, so it is somewhere in your non-defaultness.)

Comment: It looks to me like both lines start at 0,0, but because they have a greater than 1 pixel line width, they don't appear to join properly. Note that the missing corner is half the width and height of the lines. Can you set solid_capstyle: projecting for the lines? (I may have the syntax wrong.)

Comment: @user3757614 solid_capstyle: projecting option does not exist. However, lines.solid_capstyle : projecting exists, but it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Which Version of `Matplotlib` are you using?

This appears to be a known bug in `Matplotlib` Version 1.3.1, which is still the standard one for my Ubuntu. I upgraded to 1.4 and now everything works fine. You have to manually (more or less) build Version 1.4, however...

Comment: You are absolutely right, I just updated and it fixed the problem